# Algorithm for finding a solution/parameter that makes multiple Parameterized Infinite Summation Series equal?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

Consider 4 infinite summation series $S_0(n, a, b)$, $S_1(n, a, b)$, $S_2(n, a, b)$, $S_3(n, a, b)$. The parameters $a, b$ are positive real number inputs to the functions/terms in each of the series.

Is there an algorithm such that:

Finds a function $F(a, b) = C_0$ that is satisfiable for those pair of values $(a, b)$ for which each of the series is convergent and: $\Sigma S_0(n, a, b) =\Sigma S_1(n, a, b)=\Sigma S_2(n, a, b)=\Sigma S_3(n, a, b)$.

The function must be real valued and not another infinite series of some sorts (if possible).

Alternatively,  if such a generic function is difficult, we can get the first few values/roots of $b$ for which $\Sigma S_0(n, a, b) =\Sigma S_1(n, a, b)=\Sigma S_2(n, a, b)=\Sigma S_3(n, a, b)$. Essentially, we need to find the first few values of $b$ for which all series converge to a same sum.

I haven't found much regarding parameterized infinite series and this problem. But I believe a natural problem like this must have been studied. Anyone please?

Comment: can someone please help?

Comment: Where did you come across this problem? You can define such a function as $$F(a,b) = \left(\sum S_0(n, a, b) - \sum S_1(n, a, b)\right)^2 \\+\left(\sum S_1(n, a, b) - \sum S_2(n, a, b)\right)^2 \\+ \left(\sum S_2(n, a, b) - \sum S_3(n, a, b)\right)^2$$ But that is as far as you can go with generic $S_i$ series. There is no magic fairy that is somehow going to reduce this to a neat formula not involving the summations when we don't know anything about the $S_i$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair This has to do with infinite series where both $b, c$ and $C_0-b, c$ give the same result for some given constant $C_0$. Given that we know the generic series and we can create at least two (or 4) summations, I was wondering if we can solve it using this property. The line of thought was in traditional algebra when we have 2 unknowns and 2 or more equations we can solve the problem easily. I was wondering if some similar approach is possible here?

Comment: You keep referring to "$c$" as if it should be meaningful, even though you haven't used it in any formula or defined it in some other way. And what specifically do you mean by "both $b,c$ and $C_0−b,c$ give the same result". Understand that we cannot see what is going on in your head. You have to explain it carefully.

Comment: Sorry! My sincere apologies. Its a typo! Let me go step by step. (1) There are 4 infinite series each of which take 2 input parameters: positive real numbers $a, b$. (2) For some values of $a, b$ each series converges to exactly the same sum (lets call it $T$). (3) Now for the specific values $a, b$ for which they converge to $T$,  its known that for values $C_0-a, b$ they will also converge to $T$ again, where $C_0, T$ are some constants given to us beforehand. Now the Q is: Can we find the smallest value of $b$ which converges them to sum $T$?

Comment: Not without knowing something about how the series terms depend on $b$. The fact that you know a couple of $a$ values for which it works is immaterial to $b$. It is easy to come up with examples fitting all your information, yet converge to $T$ for any desired range for $b$. There is just no information provided that would give way of determining $b$ values.